# only home page is not working all other working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When tried to open http://client.del:8080/coupon/ its redirected to http://client.del/coupon/ on my virtual machine

only home page is not working all other working in wordpress

please suggest anyone

Comment: Be aware that there is a dedicated wordpress stackexchange, that may get you  better answers

Comment: i tried there too...but still not getting anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the "siteurl" and "home" options in wp_options mysql table ?
It should contain your url with :8080